# update listbox on textbox change asp.net

Tags: asp.net

could any one please help me how to accomplish in asp.net my problem? I have a server control textbox and listbox. What I want to happen is than when I type something on the textbox, on keypress, the contents of the listbox is also updated(realtime) and will filter the result accordingly. If textbox has been cleared, all original values from the listbox will come back.

Comment: Although not exactly what you want, have a look at the [Ajax ListSearchExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ListSearch/ListSearch.aspx).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter I already checked on that but it does not fit my requirements. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery for textbox

```
$("#<%=txtboxID.ClientID %>").keydown(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your action
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how do i call server side action from //your action? Sorry I'm not that familiar yet with jquery. Can you also elaborate more? Thank you.

Comment: depends on what you need to do. could you elaborate your desired functionality?
Other option is to call button click from JQuery like this:
$("#<%=buttonID.ClientID %>").click();
Make sure you have that button set to "display: none" so users can't see & click on it

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give a roughly code snippet regarding that? I just need one text box and one list box. If anything is typed in the textbox, the listbox will automatically filtered based on what has been typed in the textbox. More of like when we are doing search in google but instead i want to display filtered results in a list box. Thank you.